# how to run a function at certain time using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, recurrence

In my app, i have implemented functionality to check app version using bundleVersion String. Now, i want to run this function everyday at 8:00 a.m. This is kiosk based app which does not go into background. So, app would be active all the time.

I am using `UILocalnotification` to schedule a notification for that time. Now, my app has other `UILocalnotification` as well. I am not sure how can i identify notifications in app delegate `didReceiveLocalNotification()` method.

My method to schedule notification is below

```
func scheduleNotification() {

    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    let notif = UILocalNotification()


    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date = NSDate()

    var calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()

    calendarComponents = calendar.components([.Day,.Month,.Year], fromDate: date)

    let day = calendarComponents.day
    let month = calendarComponents.month
    let year = calendarComponents.year

    calendarComponents.day = day
    calendarComponents.month = month
    calendarComponents.year = year

    calendarComponents.hour = 8
    calendarComponents.second = 0
    calendarComponents.minute = 0
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
    let dateToFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)


    notif.fireDate = dateToFire
    notif.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
    notif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.NSWeekdayCalendarUnit


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notif)

}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-uilocalnotification

Comment: Well, you can save a identifier in userInfo object in your generated UILocalNotification. See apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo

Comment: @pedrouan: Thanks for reply. I don't know how notification is not getting fired and didRecivedNotification method not called.

Answer (score -1):

Following method could help you to execute any task at regular interval , i used this method to call webservice at regular interval to provide searching functionality :

```
let debounceTimer : NSTimer?
func test() {

        if let timer = debounceTimer {

            timer.invalidate()

        }

        debounceTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("putmethodnamewhichneedstocall"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(debounceTimer!, forMode: "NSDefaultRunLoopMode")

    }
```

For specific time daily Refer to this **SO** link  :[Repeating local notification daily at a set time with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619998/repeating-local-notification-daily-at-a-set-time-with-swift)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. I need to run function daily at 8:00 am. With NSTimer , i need to specify the interval. It wouldn't be feasible to give time interval.

Comment: updated code with reference link , use this to trigger timer accordingly